# Nopcommerce application restart stop visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, application-restart, nopcommerce-4.0

When I restart nopCommerce 4.0 application from admin side it always stop visual studio and as well as application.

Same thing happening on Plugin install and uninstall time.
It's take too much time for build and run project every time on restart application and plugin install/uninstall moment.

There is any solution for that than let me know.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need to select your project solution for run project instead of IIS.
Please check below image.

[image]

Comment: It's working fine with me for prevent stop VS. It prevent stop visual studio on restart and install/uninstall plugin,but one issue still, plugin not install/uninstall proper.